# How to prove a polynomials roots are integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble finding a direct way to prove questions like the following:

$$
\exists x\in\mathbb{Z} |x^2+x=271
$$

Now, I know this is false, because $$x^2+x-271=0$$ 
$$x= \frac12(-1-\sqrt{1085}),\frac12(\sqrt{1085}-1) $$

Neither of which are integers, so by negating the statement I get where I am stuck at - how can I prove that a polynomials roots are integers?

I should point out that I am taking my first discrete mathematics course, so if anyone can guide me somewhere, or shed some light on how I'm supposed to prove statements like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factorise as $x(x+1)=271$ - what are the factors of $271$?

Suppose $a,b,c$ are integers, and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then $x(ax+b)=-c$ so if $x$ is an integer it is a factor of the constant term $c$. Check the factors to see if they work.

You will discover other criteria as you progress - testing for the existence of integer solutions of equations has produced creative mathematics over many years - each generation building on the last.

Answer (score 3):

All rational roots of a polynomial have to divide  271. Hence all integer solutions have to divide 271. Show that no positive or negative factor of 271 is a zero of your polynomial 
$$x^2+x-271$$

Also note that 271 is a prime number.

Please see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem for more information regarding rational root theorem.Understanding this theorem will allow you to attack more general versions of the problem you have posted above.